# Set text color to title of sherlokactionbar for android devices having 2.3

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, title

I am using **actionbarsherlok** library for my android project to support actionbar for below 3.0 devices.I managed to change text color to black/Blue for actionbar title for particular screens on above android 3.0 .
For this to achieve ,I found this which is working on above android 3.0

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
        "android");

    TextView titleTv= (TextView) findViewById(titleId);

    if(titleTv!= null){

            titleTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
            titleTv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                    "helvetica_medium.otf"));
    }
```

But, for devices having android 2.3 ,I am getting titleTv= null.
Is there any solution for this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of searching finally got the answer 
I just added this to style.xml

```
 <style name="Actionbar.Music.TitleText" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.SherlockActionBarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance</item>
</style>

<style name="MyApp.ActionBar.TextAppearance" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

and used that theme for activity for which I wanted title to be blue/black

```
 android:theme="@style/Actionbar.Music.TitleText"
```

Also with below code in oncreate of that activity whose actionbar title color I wanted to be blue/black

```
int titleId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id",
    "android");

TextView titleTv= (TextView) findViewById(titleId);

if(titleTv!= null){

        titleTv.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
        titleTv.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
                "helvetica_medium.otf"));
}
```